# How do I disable linking output in the build log?

Tags: c++, build, mingw, codeblocks

I apologize for the question being too simple, but I cannot seem to find it anywhere...

I am wondering where I can find the options to disable the linking output in my build log. I have over 1000 lines of output as the example:

`-I..\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\OgrePlugins`

IDE: Code::Blocks 12.11
Compiler: MinGW (Shouldn't matter much)

Comment: Could you share you build options, the only thing i can find in quick references to gcc is not using -v .. if you are using -v(which prints compilation information that the IDE needs to show build errors..) then you can try not using it, IF the ide will even let you. You have to realize that with gcc, it is part of the gnu tool chain, and NOT integrated with any ide. The IDE's built around it merely invoke it as if it would be invoked from the shell, and parse it's output. Overall your not going to get as nice of a development experience with gcc.

Comment: Also, the best IDE that iv'e came across to use with gcc, is QtCreator, nokia really did an excellent job on that IDE, and yes it can be used for non Qt projects. We use it where i work, and most of the UI we do is fluid.

Comment: @johnathon I am confident that I can disable it. My old project did not output every single linker like such. I will search around my build options to see if I can find anything. As for sharing them, I will also find that out just incase.

Comment: After some testing with my old project I noticed that the same output is occuring, meaning this must be integrated with the new version of gcc. I guess I will have to deal with it unless theres an alternate solution...